# Hibernate Spatial - Query within an X kilometer radius?

Tags: java, jts-topology-suite, hibernate-spatial

I am new to Hibernate Spatial, and am trying to perform a simple query of objects within a given radius.  I've created a number of entries in my database with properties corresponding to a latitude and longitude, using data from Google Maps and other sources.  This property is defined like this in my Entity class:

```
@Column
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Point coordinates = null;
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to do a search of all entity objects that have coordinates that fall within a radius of *x* kilometers from a given point.  For example, I'd like to find objects that fall within a 50 kilometer radius of the point (12.34567, -76.54321).  However, I can't find any examples or tutorials that would explain how to do this in Hibernate Spatial.

Can anyone give me any information on how a query like this can be constructed?